# Changing variable values in for loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, scope

I'm confused about how variables modified in part of a `for` loop behave outside the loop. Encountered this problem when doing a more complicated analysis but realised it's a basic `for` loop issue, easily shown with a toy example:

```
x, y, z = 1, 2, 3

for i in [x, y, z]:
    i += 10
    print(i)

# prints 11
# prints 12
# prints 13

print(x, y, z)
# prints 1 2 3
```

I would've expected the change to each iterated-over variable in the loop to stick outside of the loop, but evidently this isn't the case. I gather it's probably something about variable scope? Could someone explain how this works?

Comment: Your understanding problem is that `i` refers to a certain object in each iteration, but then you immediately change `i` to refer to another object of value, say, `x + 10`. This has no connection with original `x`. Besides, `x` is an immutable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you don't even need a `for loop` to showcase this what you call an issue but is actually not.

Take this simpler example:

```
x = 1
i = x
i += 10
print(x)
print(i)
```

Ofcourse `x` is not modified because it holds an immutable value of `1`.

Here are immutable types in Python:

- all primitive types: `int`, `float`, `bool`
- plus `tuple` and `str`

**Immutability** means **no shared reference**.
So that when you have:
`x = 1`
`y = 1`
doesn't mean that `x` and `y` are referring to the same exact value `1` but instead each of the two variables have their "duplicate" instance of the same value. So that changing `x` doesn't affect `y` at all.

The same way, when you have:
`x = 1`
`i = x`
this is going to create a "brand new value of `1`" and assign it to `i`, so that modifying `i` doesn't affect variable `x` at all.

But now, to get the behavior you want you can do something like:

```
x, y, z = 1, 2, 3
l = [x, y, z]
for i in range(len(l)):
    l[i] += 10
x, y, z = l
```

Or if you really really want to be a little bit quirky, you can do:

```
x, y, z = 1, 2, 3
for var in locals().keys():
    if var in ['x', 'y', 'z']:
        locals()[var] += 10
```

But keep in mind that it is a good design decision from the creators of the language to keep certain types immutable, and so you should work with it instead and completely avoid using `locals()` as above or something else unnatural.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation! I get what you're saying about no shared reference and how modifying `i` doesn't affect `x`. I'm less sure what it has to do with immutability. If I assign `i = 1` isn't that an immutable type as well? but I can nonetheless later assign `i += 10`, yielding `11`.

Comment: Actually when you do `i += 10` it is not modifying directly the value but `copying` it first then do the `calculation` and finally `reassign` the result to `i`. It could look like something like this:

`i = 1 (# initialization)

temp = i (# copying)

i = temp + 10 (# computing then reassigning)`

Answer (score 1):

Actually it is not related to scopes.

Here you are iterating using the value i and increasing only i value, not any of x,y or z variable. So x,y and z remain unchnaged.

To change, use like this:

```
b = {'x': 1,'y': 2, ,'z': 3}
for m in b.keys():
  b[m] += 10
```

Comment: I think OP is asking *why* this is the case.

Comment: @AMC the explanation is also included

Comment: I don't think this is the complete picture.  If you iterate over a list of lists, you can mutate the lists: `l = [[1],[2]]; for j in l:    j.append(4)` will modify `l` in place

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that `i` variable is like a "temporary" variable in the `for` statement. So you are assigning `i` to a value of the array in each iteration. Look at the next example:

```python
array = [1, 2, 3]

for i in array:
    i += 10 #here we are modifying the "temporary" variable
    
print(array) #prints 1 2 3

index = 0
for i in array:
    array[index] += 10 #here we are modifying the array
    index += 1
    
print(array) #prints 11 12 13
```